# Maven Environment Setup Windows 7 error

Tags: java, maven, installation

I want to learn more about JSF framework but its first step is to install MAVEN. I followed all the steps in installing Maven [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/pdf/maven_environment_setup.pdf). I've downloaded the file **"apache-maven-3.3.3-bin.zip"** [here](http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi). When I open the command prompt and typed **"mvn --version"** I got the following error.

[image]

I've also set my environment variables on system variables panel.

[image]

The M2_HOME full directory is *C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.3.3*

and the **JAVA_HOME** directory *C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_51*

And I checked also the version of JAVA I'm using.

[image]

Comment: Add a blank beween -Xms256m and -Xmx ...

Answer (score 1):

Your global maven options (environment variable `MAVEN_OPTS`) is invalid. You must separate the options with a space:

```
MAVEN_OPTS = -Xms256m -Xmx512m
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally no need to add `MAVEN_OPTS` but as you added you have to give space between two arguments.

```
 MAVEN_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx512m
```